# Django return format_html

Tags: python, django

I have a function to return an result in an **html_format**, but I can´t figure out how to return the *value* in a dynamic way. Currently this is what I have:

[image]

> this is the function:

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>Imagen</a>', value)
```

As you can see I have the value *'Image'* hardcoded, but what I want is the name of the Image, something like this *'CFE.jpg'* to be shown.

I have tried this:

```
return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>{}</a>', value)
```

but I get a Index Tuple error

also I have tried:

```
return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>{{object.id}}</a>', value)
```

but in the front end it only shows a '{}'

**Update**

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        try:
            path = value
            name = value.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
            if name:
                return format_html('<a href="/media/{0}" download>{0}</a>', path, name)
        except:
            ValidationError
```

[image]

I added the try because I was receiving an ImageField split error.

Comment: Try `return format_html('<a href="/media/{0}" download>{0}</a>', value)` or `return format_html('<a href="/media/{img}" download>{img}</a>', img=value)`.

Comment: thanks! first option worked, it is showing the folder and the file, is there a way to only show the file name? e.g picture/cfe.jpg to only show cfe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `value` is the name of the file you can simply do

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return format_html('<a href="/media/{0}" download>{0}</a>', value)
```

If it is the full path you can use

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        path = value
        name = value.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
        return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>{}</a>', path, name)
```

The `split("/")[-1]` will give you the last part of the path (so CFE.jpg)
The `split("?")[0]` will discard any query parameters you might have.

---

*Edit:*
Since you've added the `value` is an `ImageFieldFile` you can use it's `name` for the split.

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        path = value.name
        name = path.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
        return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>{}</a>', path, name)
```

Split is a method on strings. The file has attributes like name, url, etc. which can be used.
It might be better for you to use `return format_html('<a href="{}" download>{}</a>', value.url, name)` for the url. This will prefix the `settings.MEDIA_URL` to the file name/path just like you are doing. The advantage is you can change the url for all your media by just updating the settings rather than going to each place and updating it.

---

**Edit:** As requested I'm adding the output that I got when I tried this

```
 In [5]: type(value) 
 Out[5]: django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile 
 In [6]: value.name 
 Out[6]: 'private/logos/example_kfBWEZh.jpg'
 In [7]: value.name.split("/")[-1]
 Out[7]: 'example_kfBWEZh.jpg
```

Note that `value` is an `ImageFieldFile`, `value.name` is a string on which I can call `.split()`.

Comment: I'm getting a ''ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'split'', I will update my question with what I tried

Comment: Ah, I might have missed that. Use `value.name` for the split.

Comment: Hi, I don´t understand if path = value.name and in the name = path.split.... technically is using value.name, is that what you mean?

Comment: it is not working, I also tried with os. path and I have not been lucky to make it work, do you have any other idea?

Comment: What error do you get? I tried this and it seems to work for me            
In [5]: type(value)          
Out[5]: django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile       
In [6]: value.name       
Out[6]: 'private/logos/example_kfBWEZh.jpg'        
In [7]: value.name.split("/")[-1]         
Out[7]: 'example_kfBWEZh.jpg'

Comment: Can you post it in your Answer? I tried to follow the code but I think I'm missing something because of the format in the comment I cannot figure it out correctly.